# SOAP request in PHP with CURL - soapenv:Envelope

Tags: php, curl, soap

I have a request that i am sending using SOAP via curl and i am pretty sure i have the request working but i am getting the following error

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
        <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Request XML Schema Validation failed. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'soapenv:Envelope'.</faultstring>
    </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Has anyone seen this error?? I am stringing the request using php and then passing it into the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` using CURL

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error depends on the server,

In any case you should otherwise use a WSDL to php generator instead or using CURL directly as it would ensure you that the XML request is well constructed from PHP objects. The PHP SoapClient handles pretty any Web Service. Pretty any generated PHP SDK using the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project works like a charm. If not, you can too override the SoapClient instance in order to implement your own logic for the request.